# How do I make my searchbar responsive in tailwindcss?

Tags: grid, tailwind-css

I have a nav with a logo, searchbar, logout button and a profile picture.

I want the logo on the left, the logout & profile picture on the right and the searchbar should be in the middle.

I have achieved this, but I want the searchbar to get wider when the screens goes from mobile to ipad to desktop.

I tried using `grid-cols-3` for mobile and for 640px and above `sm:grid-cols-4` and then on the logo `sm:col-span-1` on the search bar `sm:col-span-2` and on the logout & picture `sm:col-span:1.`

The input has `w-full` so I expected it to get bigger since that div now has a width of 2 colums if I understand correctly but it stays the same size.

*my full code:*

```
<body>
  <nav class="bg-gray-700">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-4">
      <div class="pt-3 pb-2.5 ml-5 sm:col-span-1">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="w-50 h-7"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="flex mt-[2px] sm:col-span-2">
        <form class="flex h-9">
          <div class="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="text-base mt-2 p-1.5 rounded-l h-7 bg-white w-full">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="text-sm cursor-pointer rounded-r mt-2 px-2 bg-blue-600">
            <i class="fa fa-search relative top-[0.75px]"></i>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="mt-1 flex flex-row-reverse sm:col-span-1">
        <div class="mt-2 mr-5 ml-2 relative bottom-[2px]">
          <a href="logout.php" class="text-sm underline text-white">Logout</a>
        </div>
        <img src="https://api.lorem.space/image/face?w=150&h=150" alt="profile picture" class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full mt-[1px]">
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: can you try this `md:flex-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Yilmaz* commented, the solution is **flex-1**!